# Oracle Plsql dynamic select as a parameter

Tags: oracle, dynamic, plsql, bind

I have a `procedure A` which takes as parameter a select statement but I want my select to be dynamic.

```
Proc A (query);


Proc B is
Declare
-- try 1 using variables
q varchar2(200):= 'select xy from table where col =' || var ;

-- try 2 using bind
q varchar2(200):= 'select xy from table where col = :v' ;

Begin

-- here i want to be able to define a variable based on certain conditions and my string q will take the variable.

A(q);

End;
```

Is this possible?
Can someone help please?

Comment: Just look at "Related" section  in the right bottom of this page. You will find many such answers which will help you.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Proc_A (in_query varchar)
IS
BEGIN
  execute immediate in_query;
END;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Proc_B 
IS
  col_val varchar2(60) := 'Lady Gaga';
  q varchar2(200):= 'select * from test_table where char_col =''' || col_val || '''';
Begin
  Proc_A(q);
End;
/

begin
  Proc_B;
end;
```

But obviously for selects you'll need to pick up the resultset. DMLs (insert/delete/...) will work as described.